# SELinux: how to allow httpd to delete temp files from MySQL?

Tags: linux, centos, file-permissions, selinux

Here's the setup: I let MySQL dump tables to `/tmp` (they just contain numbers, no real data) for PHP to pick up and process. After this, the temp files are no longer needed, so I delete them with PHP (`unlink`).

Of course, SELinux does not like this. I can setup `/tmp` fine for MySQL to read/write, and PHP to read/write from it, but when PHP wants to delete the file MySQL created, it cannot. I thought it might have to do with the 'sticky bit' on `/tmp`, but that makes no difference.

I can't really find a proper solution for this problem, most solutions address the issue of making directories readable/writable to PHP (or, the httpd user that is), not deleting someone else's files.

BTW: if I turn SELinux off, PHP will delete the files without issue. So it is definitely something I have to change SELinux-wise, but what would be the best approach?

Comment: What was in the audit log?

Comment: Yes, good question. Just after posting this I had a brainwave: some time ago I did something with `audit2allow` in order to sort out a different SELinux issue. Fortunately, I could dig this up. I then scanned the `audit.log` and piped it: `grep {offending rule name} /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -a` then after reviewing that (it looked good) created a module: `grep {offending rule name} /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -a -M tmp` and added it: `semodule -i tmp.pp`. It appears all is well now...! I will monitor it for a bit and if it's still good, post this as answer.

Comment: BTW: the `audit2allow` result was actually very exact in assessing the situation: `allow httpd_t mysqld_tmp_t:file unlink;`

Comment: Also the documentation has [more explicit and detailed instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems) which you might be interested in reading.

Comment: Thanks for the link, quite helpful. I browsed the RH documentation (which is very good), but it's rather vast and I was probably searching the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment: I solved it by leveraging `audit2allow`.

1. Scan `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for the offending rule (I used the filename of the file MySQL had written)
2. Pipe the rule to `audit2allow` and review it: `grep {offending rule name} /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -a`
3. I got `allow httpd_t mysqld_tmp_t:file unlink;` from step 2, so that looked exactly like what I was after. With that result, I created a new module: `grep {offending rule name} /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -a -M tmp`. This generates a file called `tmp.pp`.
4. Import the module file: `semodule -i tmp.pp`